# Delphi simular subtração de angulos expresso em graus °, minutos ' e segundos "

Tags: delphi-7

Delphi, Lazarus

Preciso de ajuda dos amigos, um código .pas  para simular a subtração de angulos expresso em graus °, minutos ' e segundos " no Delphi ou no Lazarus, pegando os valores de dois TEdit  e dando o resultado da subtração num Label.

**Exemplo**

Subtração

```
  179°  59'   60"    TEdit1  
  70°   5'   15"    TEdit2
```

---

```
 109° 54'  45"   resposta  no  Label1
```

Answer (score 3):

Segue solução em Delphi, destaco que Edit1 e Edit2 esperam uma string válida, com o formato:
`ggº mm' ss"`

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

   function GetValorNumerico(const P_Texto: string; const P_Caracter: Char): Integer;
   begin
      case P_Caracter of
         'º': Result := StrToInt(Trim(Copy(P_Texto, 1, Pos(P_Caracter, P_Texto)-1)));
         '''': Result := StrToInt(Trim(Copy(P_Texto, Pos('º', P_Texto)+2, 2)));
         '"': Result := StrToInt(Trim(Copy(P_Texto, Pos('''', P_Texto)+2, 2)));
      end;
   end;

var
   W_Graus1: integer;
   W_Minutos1: integer;
   W_Segundos1: integer;

   W_Graus2: integer;
   W_Minutos2: integer;
   W_Segundos2: integer;

   W_Graus3: integer;
   W_Minutos3: integer;
   W_Segundos3: integer;
begin
   W_Graus1 := GetValorNumerico(Edit1.Text, 'º');
   W_Minutos1 := GetValorNumerico(Edit1.Text, '''');
   W_Segundos1 := GetValorNumerico(Edit1.Text, '"');

   W_Graus2 := GetValorNumerico(Edit2.Text, 'º');
   W_Minutos2 := GetValorNumerico(Edit2.Text, '''');
   W_Segundos2 := GetValorNumerico(Edit2.Text, '"');

   if W_Segundos1 < W_Segundos2 then
   begin
      Dec(W_Minutos1);
      Inc(W_Segundos1, 60);
   end;

   W_Segundos3 := W_Segundos1 - W_Segundos2;

   if W_Minutos1 < W_Minutos2 then
   begin
      Dec(W_Graus1);
      Inc(W_Minutos1, 60);
   end;

   W_Minutos3 := W_Minutos1 - W_Minutos2;

   W_Graus3 := W_Graus1 - W_Graus2;

   Label1.Caption := Format('%dº %d'' %d"', [W_Graus3, W_Minutos3, W_Segundos3]); 
end;
```

Comment: Oi Melissa tive problema no computador  e vi somente hoje (1 de maio)

Comment: Oi Melissa me chamo Alessandro tive problema no computador  e vi sua postagem somente hoje (1 de maio)  agradecido pelo código  vou testar ele. Obrigado